# How to get dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist MVC(VB.Net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have gone through series of tutorials to achieve this goal but none has really worked for me. I stumbled on the tutorial at the link below and also converted it for my VB.Net usage and that's the only one that ever responded but with an error: `[object Object]`. Don't know how to resolve this, can anyone please help?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Below is my code:

**Controller**

```
Public Function PullStates(ByVal id As Integer) As JsonResult  

    Dim states = db.States.Where(Function(s) s.CountryCode = id).[Select](Function(s) New With   
    {  
        Key .Text = s.Descrip,   
        Key .Value = s.Code  
    })  
    Return Json(New SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"))  

End Function  

'GET: Region/Create  
Function Create() As ActionResult  
    ViewBag.Code = "AUTO"  


    ViewBag.Country = db.Countries.[Select](Function(c) New SelectListItem With  
    {  
        .Text = c.Descrip,  
        .Value = c.CountryCode  
    })  


    Return View()  
End Function
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", CType(ViewBag.Country, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), "--Select Country--", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "tb8"}) 
@Html.DropDownList("State", New SelectList(String.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Please Select State--", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "tb8"})
```

**Script**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    <script src="~/Scripts/ddl/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="~/Scripts/ddl/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
            //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event  
            $("#Country").change(function () {  
                $("#State").empty();  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: '@Url.Action("PullStates")', // we are calling json method  
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    data: { id: $("#Country").val() },  
                    success: function (states) {  
                        // states contains the JSON formatted list  
                        // of states passed from the controller  
                        $.each(states, function (i, state) {  
                            $("#State").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');  
                        }); // here we are adding option for States  
                    },  
                    error: function (ex) {  
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);  
                    }  
                });  
                return false;  
            })  
        });  
    </script>   

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about vb.net but here you dont need to change the variable into a select list jsut directly pass like this

```
Public Function PullStates(ByVal id As Integer) As JsonResult  

        Dim states = db.States.Where(Function(s) s.CountryCode = id).[Select](Function(s) New With   
       {  
        Key .Text = s.Descrip,   
        Key .Value = s.Code  
        })  
        Return Json(states)
```

try changing your ajax success function like this

```
 success: function (data) {   
                  $(data).each(function(){
                        $("#State").append('<option value="' + this.Value + '">' + this.Text + '</option>');  
                    }); 
                },
```